# CSS Checkbox :checked Not Working with Two Toggles

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to create two different menus with two different checkbox toggles using :checked method. For some reason, I can't have two toggles even though each checkbox field has different ID's.

Here is what I'm working with: https://jsfiddle.net/keithpetrillo/owm1vk8t/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle-left">
<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle-right">

<div class="mobile-menu-wrap">

    <div class="mobile-menu-left">
        First Menu
    </div>

    <div class="mobile-menu-right">
        Second Menu
    </div>

</div>
```

The second checkbox toggle works fine, but the first only works if I remove the second. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Is this not possibe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change [**+**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-d-combinators) to [**~**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-d-combinators)

```
.mobile-menu-left, .mobile-menu-right {
  display: none;
}

#menu-toggle-left:checked ~ .mobile-menu-wrap {
  .mobile-menu-left {
    display: block;
  }
}

#menu-toggle-right:checked ~ .mobile-menu-wrap {
  .mobile-menu-right {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/owm1vk8t/1/)**

More info:

**[+ Direct adjacent combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-d-combinators)**

**[~ Indirect adjacent combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-i-combinators)**

Answer (score 2):

You just use not best selector: try "~" instead of "+". Check differences in [CSS 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

Good luck.